# How is the "Introduce Yourself" section rendered to the employer?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

When applying for a job at a company that utilizes the Jobs process (versus redirecting you to a 3rd party application), you are presented with a dialog box that has an "Introduce Yourself" section.

[image: Introduce Yourself]

How is the input here rendered to the employer? Can I use mark down or does it just display, verbatim, what I input?

Comment: Hopefully with a giant red arrow.

Comment: I'd prefer a hand-drawn circle myself, @CodyGray.

Comment: Does not support markup.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's shown as plain text. I don't think it supports markup because I tried this once (and you can to) then check your inbox (sent messages) and you'll see that the markup is just plain text.

Here is an example (I had used markup) and look at how it renders back to the employer:

[image]

From what I see usually when they support markdown they have a help link shown near the textbox as shown:

[image]

Clicking this link takes you to a mark down help (I got this one from the developer story).