# "Introduce Yourself" is not cookied - is it db driven - if so please remove?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

When applying for a job via Stack Overflow jobs, I click the apply button. The section **Introduce Yourself** always has some default text to it as shown:

[image]

I have tried clearing cookies and history and anytime I apply this comes up in the introduce yourself section. Why does this always come up? Is it stored in the database for my profile? How do I ever wipe this out completely?

Obviously this isn't stored in a cookie. My thought was we should NEVER save the introduction. When you apply for a new job it is up to the person applying to reintroduce themselves.

Related:
This is actually when I put this text in (back in January of this year (2017)) and it's stuck around ever since:

*[How is the "Introduce Yourself" section rendered to the employer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341313/how-is-the-introduce-yourself-section-rendered-to-the-employer/341400#341400)*

Comment: Is that the default text in the `<textarea>`? If so, it's part of the HTML for everybody and developers would have to remove it.

Comment: @AndrewMyers - Try to click Apply on any job - I bet you don't see the same thing I see.  This is why I asked if this is db driven based on my profile.  There should be a way for me to eliminate this text completely.  I remember putting it in a LONG time ago to test markup on this textarea.  But again that was a test done a long long time ago.

Comment: @JonH You put that in [almost a year ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341400/2315360)!

Comment: @George that post was january of this year.

Comment: @JonH you are correct, I cannot read dates...

Comment: I can't believe we just turned cookie into a verb.

Answer (score -33):

Cover letters are indeed saved and restored for the next application. It is a convenience feature.

As [Andrew](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/239394/andrew?tab=profile) pointed out in a [comment to a previous answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355926/why-does-jobs-save-my-cover-letter-between-applications-but-not-my-preferred-sk/355929#comment509772_355929):

> Applicants who change their cover letters for each job application are in the minority, and about one-fourth of applicants never change their cover letters when applying to multiple jobs. We used to avoid re-populating the cover letter on subsequent applications, but we changed that decision in part due to the data I just cited.

There is currently no way to disable this feature, though we might revisit if there is enough demand.

Comment: Umm... Sending a cover letter you wrote for someone else to someone new is probably worse than not sending one especially if it was tweaked specifically for a role name/person/other mentions. Would it make sense to have a "use my last cover letter as a template" which you have to explicitly select so that it's obvious you're doing that and you should be looking to edit it rather than mistakenly not realise you're going to send it?

Comment: The introduce yourself section being saved causes more harm then good.  I advise you guys to rethink this.

Comment: Also - would this start to make the data self-fulfulling - people are less likely to change it now it's autopopulated as err... "why bother? Looks like there's something there - let's just send it..."...

Comment: Is the pre-populated data updated after each application or is it whatever I entered the first time?

Comment: @JonClements - That and the mere fact that as far as I can tell there is no UI or page to manage this "introduce yourself" feature.  Being that it is already filled in the validation on the page passes so you may accidentally apply to a job in which your introduce me section was tailored to another job or position.

Comment: @Phaeze - Good question...this is why it shouldn't be saved.  And if it is there should be an option as Jon Clements mentioned such that I have to explicitly check a box or something to allow me to save an "introduce me section".  And the UI needs to change such that you can manage this introduction.  Asking these questions, such as the one you just asked, lends me to believe this is dangerous because of the unknowns.

Comment: @JonH yeah... like I said in my comment... I can't do anything about it, but I think blanking it out and offering a convenience option to retrieve the last one is maybe a middle ground... auto-populating it is not doing anyone any favours - especially not a developer that's not expecting it...

Comment: @JonH since this is now [meta-tag:status-bydesign], perhaps you should post a corresponding feature request.

Comment: Perhaps I'm writing my cover letters wrong, but I always change them, even just in a small way. Surely if people never changed it, it would be nearly no trouble for them to keep a copy+paste of it around and simply paste it in

Comment: @Tas you are not doing it wrong. My writing of the cover letter is the exact same way as yours.

Comment: Apparently, they made the decision to copy things because data indicated that few people write cover letters specific to each application. I suppose that code tags will be dropped soon too because new users who format their code correctly are in the minority also.

Comment: @Andrew Format code *correctly* is a different thing altogether than using code formatting. Code formatting is one of the most-used features on Stack Overflow.

Comment: When recruiting, it is actually somewhat common that you get a personal letter among the lines of "...and because of this, I think I will be a good fit for [wrong company name]". Probably happens in 1 out of 50 applications or so. Maybe SO should help the applicant to avoid such mistakes, rather than to encourage them by design.

Comment: So, because 1/4 of users violate job search best practices & choose the route that likely *prevents* them from being hired, SE made that the default behavior for 100% of users?? What the data really indicate is that many job applicants from SE are making an avoidable mistake that wastes employers' time & often leads HR to trash their application immediately. This default not only fails to prevent mistakes by lazy applicants, it *increases* the likelihood of errors for everyone else. At least now I know to avoid it. If 3/4 of users have to work around a "convenience feature," is it one?