# Remove saving Introduce Yourself and introduce option to reuse an existing introduction

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

From my prior post, which I thought was a bug:

["Introduce Yourself" is not cookied - is it db driven - if so please remove?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356442/introduce-yourself-is-not-cookied-is-it-db-driven-if-so-please-remove)

This post is for a feature request for initially setting the "Introduce Yourself" textarea to be initially empty.  Give me the option to "re-use" an existing one if I want to.

Do not default the textarea to my prior introduce yourself otherwise clicking Submit validates the page instantly and applies me for a job with an introduction that might have been for another job.

Please consider this.

Comment: It actually seems silly that that was marked as by-design instead of just changing it from bug to feature request and commenting / answering that it's by design, since you asked for it to be changed.

Comment: @Dukeling - I agree but someone asked me to repost it as a new "feature-request" - so I did!